# Idealization of Eletric Field at a point

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

According to Jackson "Classical Electrodynamics", in the first chapter about **electrostatics**:

> [...] point charges or electric fields at a point must be viewed as
>   mathematical constructs that permit a description of the phenomena at
>   the macroscopic level, but that may fail to have meaning
>   microscopically.

I think I've understood why point charges represent an idealization, but why also the electric field at a point fails to have meaning microscopically?
Moreover, what does it mean in practice that in electrostatics we are only interested in macroscopic phenomena? Does this also affect electrodynamics?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ususally talk about the EM field (as E and M together) as per QFT, and the electric and magnetic field are manifestations of the EM force.

Now you are asking why the EM field must be viewed as a mathematical construct. This means that the interaction of the EM field with other charges is mathematically modeled by virtual photons.

Virtual photons are not real particles, they are a mathematical method that we use to describe the phenomenon, when an EM field has a effect on the fabric of spacetime so, that in the region where the EM field exists (near field), it will have an effect on spacetime so that any particle that interacts with the EM field will have an altered trajectory.

These fail to have a meaning at the microscopic level, because in reality, we do not know how the EM field interacts, what we do know is that we do experiments, and we use virtual particles as a mathematical model to describe this phenomenon, and our data fit this model best (QFT).

Comment: In practice what do macroscopic phenomena mean? And also in electrodynamics do we study only macroscopic phenomena?

Comment: @AleWereWolf we usually mean macro from atom and molecule size up. smaller should be micro.

Comment: @AleWereWolf "Not quite by the distinction between macroscopic and microscopic, classical and quantum mechanics are theories that are distinguished in a subtly different way.[3] At first glance one might think of them as differing simply in the size of objects that they describe, classical objects being considered far larger as to mass and geometrical size than quantal objects, for example a football versus a fine particle of dust.

Comment: @AleWereWolf More refined consideration distinguishes classical and quantum mechanics on the basis that classical mechanics fails to recognize that matter and energy cannot be divided into infinitesimally small parcels, so that ultimately fine division reveals irreducibly granular features.

Comment: @AleWereWolf The criterion of fineness is whether or not the interactions are described in terms of Planck's constant. Roughly speaking, classical mechanics considers particles in mathematically idealized terms even as fine as geometrical points with no magnitude, still having their finite masses. Classical mechanics also considers mathematically idealized extended materials as geometrically continuously substantial.

Comment: @AleWereWolf Such idealizations are useful for most everyday calculations, but may fail entirely for molecules, atoms, photons, and other elementary particles. In many ways, classical mechanics can be considered a mainly macroscopic theory. On the much smaller scale of atoms and molecules, classical mechanics may fail, and the interactions of particles are then described by quantum mechanics. Near the absolute minimum of temperature, the Bose–Einstein condensate exhibits effects on macroscopic scale that demand description by quantum mechanics."

Comment: Thanks so much, i highly appreciate

Comment: Frankly there is more wrong with the text of this post then right. The first sentence is strange. The second paragraph is wrong: the virtual photons are a model of the field; the field interacts with charges directly. The third paragraph seems to suggest that the electromagenitc force act by altering spcae time which is simply incorrect. And the whole post concerns itself with a model of electromagnetism that is *not covered* by Jackson who is treating the classical theory.

Answer (score 1):

> why also the electric field at a point fails to have meaning microscopically?

You have no problem with a point particle being an idealization, right? Now, remember

$$
    ∇.E = ρ
$$

If you put garbage in the right hand side, do not expect anything better out of the left hand side.

> what does it mean in practice that in electrostatics we are only interested in macroscopic phenomena?

If you knew the position of a charged particle with absolute precision (assuming for now that it is still a point), then, by the uncertainty principle, you would know very little about about its velocity. Since the velocity is basically unknown (and because moving charges produce magnetic fields), you cannot have pure electrostatics at the microscopic level where quantum mechanics prevails. In the classical regime, where your charged body is made out of many charged particles, electrostatics will appear because the tiny magnetic fields average out.

By the way, if someone tells you that 'virtual photons are not real particles', ask back 'what is particle?' They might try to handwave something about [virtual being temporary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle). Ask them then 'what about resonances?'